# How do I check Javascript/jQuery/Ajax environment settings?

Tags: javascript, localhost, webserver

I'm executing the same code in my localhost server and the actual webserver and both give me different results when a particular value is null.

The actual code snipped is shown below:

```
validate: function(attrs, options) {
        var errors = [];
        if (typeof(this.get('shipping_address.' + options.key)) !== 'undefined' && this.get('shipping_address.' + options.key).length > 0 && typeof(attrs.shipping_address[options.key]) !== 'undefined' && attrs.shipping_address[options.key].length == 0) {
            console.log('trying to set an empty value key:' + options.key + " value " + this.get('shipping_address.' + options.key));
            errors.push({
                field: 'shipping_address',
                key: options.key,
                value: this.get('shipping_address.' + options.key)
            });
            return errors.length > 0 ? errors : false;
        }
    },
```

and the lines that show different results are part of the if statement and are the following:

```
this.get('shipping_address.' + options.key).length
attrs.shipping_address[options.key].length
```

P.S. options.key is part of a set of field names that could be present on a form and one form can have more fields than another.

When a particular field is not present on the form then the value that's returned is null; however, under localhost, both those lines return 0. On the other hand, the webserver returns  to both and subsequently throws "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null".

My question is how to check the environment setup? I know Javascript is browser side processing, but I'm baffled that under the same browser, localhost and the actual web server show different results and behave differently.

Comment: What do you mean by "environment setup"? There's no environment that affects how JavaScript runs. There must be some difference in the code if you're getting different values returned.

Comment: Do you use AJAX in your application? Requests to the webserver will be slower than localhost, and that timing difference could be the problem.

Comment: @Bamar: By environment set up I was imaging more of the Apache setup, PHP, or anything else that may have some sort of influence.

Comment: None of that should have any impact on JavaScript. I'll bet anything it's a timing issue.

Comment: @Bamar: I did check the timing difference, there's about 2 additional seconds delay with the web server so I'll try to delay localhost to make them somewhat equal

Comment: Don't waste time with that, figure out why your code is sensitive to timing and fix it. If you use async functions, make sure that anything that depends on it runs in the callback function.

Comment: Are there any cross domain errors (CORS) in the console? May have to loosen browser security.

Comment: I think I have some clue now. It appears to be a PHP issue where it automatically converts an empty array to null. Before the call to the PHP controller, both the webserver and the localhost have the empty fields initialised as empty arrays. After the call, the webserver returns null for the empty fields, but localhost returns the empty array.